# How to ftp a file with SparkContext.textFile?

Tags: apache-spark, ftp

I tried this scala code to download a file from a ftp site. The code is below.

```
object BasicTextFromFTP {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new org.apache.spark.SparkConf().setAppName("FTP Test")
    conf.setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val file = sc.textFile("ftp://anonymous:pandamagic@ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ls-LR.gz")
    println(file.collect().mkString("\n"))
}
}
```

I got the following error when I ran it.

> 16/02/12 10:52:22 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at BasicTextFromFTP.scala:14
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: ftp://anonymous:pandamagic@ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ls-LR.gz
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:251)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
>       at ftp.BasicTextFromFTP$.main(BasicTextFromFTP.scala:15)
>       at ftp.BasicTextFromFTP.main(BasicTextFromFTP.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

I am using spark 1.6.0 with scala 2.11.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access this FTP url ? I couldnt i know sometimes FTP is blocked in enterprise network. You might want to download this HDFS API project (https://github.com/pppsunil/HelloHDFS) and run it from command line to see if your able to get the file. YOu can find out more about the program on this blog entry http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2014/07/hdfs-java-client.html. If that basic functionality of accessing FTP url does not work then thats your problem, if not then it could be something related to spark

Comment: I have tried manual ftp and by filezilla before I posted this question. Both ways worked.